# Selecting from table where a name appears twice

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to select from a table where a name appears twice.

For example I have a table like this,

```
ID          Name
----       ------
1          Jane John
2          Kevin Smith
3          Jane John
```

What I want is for the output to show where Jane John appear twice so it should look something like this:

```
ID          Name
----       ------
1          Jane John
3          Jane John
```

I tried looking around on stackoverflow but couldn't find an exact and easy answer.

I'm using oracle SQL Developer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You ask for a record that appears twice. If a row appears three times it won't show unless you modify the having clause as commented.

```
SELECT id
    ,NAME
FROM tablen
WHERE NAME IN (
        SELECT NAME
        FROM TableN n
        GROUP BY (NAME)
        HAVING counT(NAME) = 2 --Use >1 instead of =2 for more than one record
        )
```

**EDIT**

I'll add a new solution in regard to your last comment.
As you can only ask for one field in `IN()` I'll use a special character or string making sure it does not belongs to valid values in any field.
Look at this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2af55/3

```
SELECT id
    ,NAME
    ,name2
FROM tablen
WHERE concat(NAME,'=',name2) IN (
        SELECT concat(NAME,'=',name2)
        FROM TableN n
        GROUP BY concat(NAME,'=',name2)
        HAVING count(concat(NAME,'=',name2)) = 2
        )
```

Note I wrote this thinking in SQL Server, not sure if concat function works as well in Oracle or look for an alternative.

Comment: This is perfect but also what if I wanted to check multiple columns. So let say I added another column called "Name2" and at ID 1 and 3 they have the same name  "Jack Fish". How would I get it so it prints out the repeated name in the column "Name" and "Name2"